# Get absolute URL to listitem's default display form

Tags: 2013, development, url, object-model, ssom

I need to have an absolute URL of a listitem's display form - currently I do it the following way:

On http://example.com/:

```
item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Url.TrimEnd('/') //"http://example.com"
+ "/" 
+ item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl.Trim('/')//"Lists/WorkflowTasks/DispForm.aspx"
+ "?ID=" + item.ID //"?ID=1"
```

This gets me the correct URL, meaning http://example.com/Lists/WorkflowTasks/DispForm.aspx?ID=1.

However this fails when my site collection is on a slightly more sophisticated host url, for example http://example.com/sites/secondsite/ - both methods from my code return the url containing the "/sites/secondsite/ part so I end up with http://example.com/sites/secondsite/sites/secondsite/Lists/etc...

How do I code it in a more reliable way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of methods for this available in the object model without the need to handle the slashes etc yourself, one method using [MakeFullUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.makefullurl.aspx):

```
var fullUrl = item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl);
```

> Parameters
>
> strUrl
>
> Type: System.String
>
> A string that specifies the
>   server-relative URL.
>
> Return value Type: System.String
>
> A string that
>   contains the full URL.

Comment: You forgot to add `+ "?ID=" + item.ID` at the end to fulfill OP's request.

Comment: yes you have to add id to this then it gives us 100% result as we want

Comment: var itemId = "?ID=" + item.ID;
                        var fullUrl = item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + itemId);

Answer (score 2):

```
var parentWebUrl = item.ParentList.ParentWebUrl;
var displayFormUrl = item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
var itemIdQuery = "?ID=" + item.ID;
var fullUrl = parentWeblUrl.EndWith('/') ? parentWebUrl + displayFormUrl + itemIdQuery : 
                                           parentWebUrl + "/" + displayFormUrl + itemIdQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shut down my VM and hence can't test but how about using something like `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` in combination with `SPList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl`. Note that `SPWeb.Url` gets the absolute URL for the website.

Comment: Seeing that the site collection is over at /sites/secondsite and DefaultDisplayFormUrl also contains that string in its returned url I don't think that's the way to go