# How to identify SPSite and SPWeb in URL?

Tags: 2007

Can I split the URL to `SPSite` part and `SPWeb` part?

consider the follwing:

```
http://abc/sites/john/_layouts/15/start.aspx
```

I can easliy to split the URL to `SPSite: http://abc/sites/john/` and `SPWeb : ""`

However, I am scared that there are much more structure of SharePoint URL which I cannot split by the above way

Update:

if a URL like:

```
http://abc/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/k/lib1/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

i can find the `SPSite part: http://abc/` and the `library part: /lib1/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. How about the `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/k/`? which of them is site collection? Which of them is subsite?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @SharePointGoa please check my update

Comment: url depends on how you configure your managed paths. read it here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc261845.aspx

Comment: @SharePointGoa i have an idea, can i just split them by "/" to use spsite.webs to check the next component is spsite or spweb in a for loop?

Comment: @SharePointGoa what i want to do is about someone pass a SPList URL to me and i need to get the item by that URL..

Comment: this might help?http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/get-absolute-url-to-listitems-default-display-form

Comment: @SharePointGoa that link is about use the spitem to find out the URL part. My problem is about to find out the URL part in order to get the spitem!! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `SPSite` object from the specified url, and open an `SPWeb` in that site. From there you can retrieve the segments you need.

```
string url = "http://abc/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/k/lib1/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    string sitePart = site.Url;
    string webRelativeUrl = url.Replace(sitePart, string.Empty);

    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webRelativeUrl, false)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Notice the `false` parameter in the `OpenWeb()` method. This specifies that the provided URL does not have to be an exact web url, but can be the url of a page in the web - which would be the case in your example.*

Comment: i get error from catch block which about " invalid URL /d/e/f/g/h/i/k/lib1/Forms/AllItems.aspx""

Comment: maybe i have to find out the library part first (it is easy), then webRelativeUrl.replace(libraryPart, string.Empty);

Comment: @kingyau now that you mention, I think it should indeed be the server relative url and not the site relative url. Can you try by doing: `string webRelativeUrl = url.Replace(new Uri(sitePart).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), string.Empty);` I'll update my answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP2013. You can get the site and web `url` using `_spPageContextInfo` on client side.

1. for web : `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`
2. for site : `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`

Hope this what you are looking for

Comment: two things, it is sharepoint 2007 and it is server side console application